# React native : Iterate on a JSON object without getting undefined function

Tags: javascript, android, json, react-native

I'm new to React-Native and I'm learning this by tutorials and examples all over the web. I am trying to do something very simple but it has been a week since I hit this problem and after digging StackOverflow and many other contents, none of them could help. So I decided to ask it directy. My apologies if the question looks duplicate or it seems silly.

I am trying to iterate over a JSON object and display it. All I want to do right now is to show each JSON object with its title (username). I'm planning to do much more - make the title a button and show the details of user after hitting button - but right now this is the big rock I've hit into.

Here is my code. Please note my comment on fetchdata method :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, ListView } from 'react-native'

class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {
  _onPress = () => {
    this.props.onPressItem(this.props.id);
  };

  render() {
    const textColor = this.props.selected ? "red" : "black";
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
        <View>
          <Text style={{ color: textColor }}>
            {this.props.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default class HttpExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: '',
    username: [],
    first_name: '',
    last_name: ''
  };
  //Using ES6 we need to bind methods to access 'this'
  this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }
   componentDidMount() {
     this.fetchData();
   }

    fetchData() {

      // The first line - which is commented - returns all of non-admin
      // users, the second one returns only one user. Note that the 
      // second one works fine and the first one does not.

      // fetch('http://URL/users.json', {
        fetch('http://URL/users/12345678001.json', {
         method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log(responseJson);

         this.setState({
           data: responseJson,
           username: responseJson.username,
           first_name: responseJson.first_name,
           last_name: responseJson.last_name
         })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
      });
   }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  _onPressItem = (id: string) => {
    // updater functions are preferred for transactional updates
    this.setState((state) => {
      // copy the map rather than modifying state.
      const selected = new Map(state.selected);
      selected.set(id, !selected.get(id)); // toggle
      return {selected};
    });
  };

   _renderItem = ({item}) => (
  <MyListItem
    id={item}
    onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
    title={this.state.username}
  />
);

   render() {
      return (
        <FlatList
    data={[this.state.data]}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
  />
      )
   }
}
```

And here is a sample of one of my JSON objects created by Django ReST framework, written by myself. I've just simplified the object a bit and removed some of the fields, for better reading (The avatar field is a base64 image field and it is much smaller than the original one):

```
    {
  "username": "12345678003",
  "email" : "sample@gmail.com",
  "first_name": "AAA",
  "last_name": "BBB",
  "phone_number": "12045678000",
  "gender": "M",
  "city": "NY",
  "description": "",
  "date_of_birth": "2010-03-28",
  "avatar": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
  "groups": [1,2],
  "user_permissions": [],
  "interests": [1,2]
}
```

The above is what I get by calling http://URL/users/12345678001.json which returns one user. I have been able to show the user as one touchable opacity in the application (the above code works) But when I call users.json which has a structure like below:

```
[{user1 data},{user2 data}, etc.]
```

I cannot make the mobile application display each user's username in the mobile output. Either I get nothing (nothing is displayed) or the usual errors pop up (TypeError: object is not a function, etc.) I want to have the application iterate through the whole users.json and show each user's username as one touchable opacity. I've tried using .map which throws me the error, or calling each object in `responseJson` by their array index which either shows me nothing or throws error.

Let me know about your ideas and solutions.

FYI, I am testing this on my Nexus 5X phone directly.

### Update

Here is an example of users.json as it reflects in my console log :

```
[{
"username": "12345678001",
"email" : "sample@gmail.com",
"first_name": "AAA",
"last_name": "BBB",
"phone_number": "12045678000",
"gender": "M",
"city": "NY",
"description": "",
"date_of_birth": "2010-03-28",
"avatar": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
"groups": [1,2],
"user_permissions": [],
"interests": [1,2]
},
{
"username": "12345678003",
"email" : "sample@gmail.com",
"first_name": "AAA",
"last_name": "BBB",
"phone_number": "12045678003",
"gender": "M",
"city": "NY",
"description": "",
"date_of_birth": "2010-12-20",
"avatar": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
"groups": [1,2],
"user_permissions": [],
"interests": [1,2]
}]
```

### Another Update

As requested, here is a screenshot of my console, note that it differs from what I've posted here and has many different fields :

[image]

### More Investigation:

I decided to make the code much simpler, and just focus on the main problem. How to return the iterated object for display:

My code is now this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, ListView } from 'react-native'

export default class HttpExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  data = [''];
  }

    fetchData() {
      fetch('http://URL/users.json', {
         method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log("ResponseJson is :" + responseJson);
         console.log(responseJson.users.length);
         console.log(responseJson.users.username);
         console.log(responseJson.users);
         console.log("THIS:::" + responseJson.users[0].username);
         responseJson.users.map((user) =>
       {
         console.log("THIS:::" + user.username);
         data.push(user.username);
         console.log("This.data:" + data[0] + "second:" + data[1]);
       });
         return data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
      });
   }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

   render() {
      return (
  <View>
 <ListView
   dataSource={this.fetchData()}
   renderRow={(data) => <Text>{data.username}</Text>}
  />
  </View>
      )
   }
}
```

All of the "console.log" commands return with correct info (Check the end of the post), but my `render` does not work and throws undefined is not a object. I really don't understand what is the exact problem? isn't `data` an array? Why it can't be displayed and throws `TypeError`? What am I getting wrong?

console.log outputs, in correct order :

```
ResponseJson is :[object Object]
3
undefined
(whole users.json is returned)
THIS:::12345678001
THIS:::12345678001
This.data:second:12345678001
THIS:::12345678002
This.data:second:12345678001
THIS:::12345678003
This.data:second:12345678001
```

Comment: Input to flatlist should be an array. Your JSON is not an array

Comment: how exactly the responseJson object in case 2 or more user. Can u please give an example. I mean if  it will be like this {key1:  user1Detail,  key2: user2Details} ?

Comment: would you mind taking a screenshot of your console?

Comment: btw in your _onPressItem, why are you passing params as `id: string`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Harrison I've just copied-and-pasted that part of code, I'm still trying to make this work, then remove and refactor whatever is unnecessary.